# Can you batch change per-file compiler flags in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'd like to be able to change compiler flags for a whole set of files.

When accessing per-file compiler flags from the "Build Phases" area you can change flags one at a time, however say I'd like to change the flags for every file in a group (e.g., the DropBox or Facebook SDK).

Anyone know how to do this in Xcode 4.0.x?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fortunately, YES :-)

In Targets->Build Phaes->Compile Sources, mark all the files you like to set a compiler flag for, press RETURN (hit the enter key!), put the flag in the upcoming window and you're done!

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this tip - that's a great hidden feature.

Comment: OMG! This will be a great time saver… For some odd reason, multi-selection + double click on a file does not do the job. You really need to type *return* for the change to be propagated to all the selected file.

Comment: You can also use search feature to filter out files.